# Error occurs when decoding XDR with SafeUnmarshalBase64

Tags: xdr, go-sdk

Error can be seen while trying to decode the stellar XDR with Golang as

```
switch '2' is not valid enum value for union
```

Following Go Code has been used.

```
  var txe xdr.Transaction
    errXDR := xdr.SafeUnmarshalBase64(envelopeXDR, &txe)

    if errXDR != nil {
        log.Error("Error while SafeUnmarshalBase64 " + errXDR.Error())
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusBadRequest)
        response := model.Error{Message: "Error while SafeUnmarshalBase64 " + errXDR.Error()}
        json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(response)
        return nil
    }
```

Any help is highly appreciate on finding the correct way of decoding XDR with latest libraries